# friend operator confusion

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, header-files, friend

I'm new to using .h/.cpp files and I'm trying to convert my .cpp to .h and .cpp and I'm running into this issue. It's erroring and I'm not sure how to resolve it. In Primitives.h I have:

```
friend Matrix operator+(const Matrix&, const Matrix&);
```

and in Primitives.cpp I had:

```
    friend Matrix operator+ (const double b, const Matrix& a)
```

But thus far my attempts to change the format have not worked. Any tips?

Comment: what is the error? is the operator+ declared before appearing in the friend declaration?

Comment: The type of the first argument differs. Why is it double in the implementation?

Comment: Hi, can you post some more of the code? The impression you give us is that you have two overloads of the same operator; one that adds two `Matrix` elements and another that adds a `double` scalar to a `Matrix`. But with just your question, it's impossible to help you!

Comment: did you take any effort checking any documentation of c++? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/465sdshe.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You should do it like this:

```
// header
class Matrix
{
public:
    friend Matrix operator+(const Matrix&, const Matrix&);
};

// source
Matrix operator+(const Matrix&, const Matrix&) { ... }
```

For short operators it may be more convenient to define the operator directly in the header file:

```
// header
class Matrix
{
public:
    friend Matrix operator+(const Matrix&, const Matrix&) {
        // code here
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not use `friend` in implementation (`.cpp` file). You should use it at declaration (in `.h` file) only.

Comment: If i use `friend` in a implementation (.cpp file). is it right?

Comment: No. All 'social' things -- friends, function declarations for other modules and other things MUST be declared in header file only.

Just imagine You're writing a library another dev is using. He will have access to headers but not to [compiled] libraries. And yes, he want to see all declared items (friends included) in his module.

Comment: I mean, i write `friend` both in `.h` and `.cpp` files, is it right?

Comment: No, this is not right. You should write `friend` only in `.h`. This is enogh.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
///your.h
class Matrix
{
    //your class
    friend Matrix operator+ (const double b, const Matrix& a);
};

////your.cpp
Matrix operator+ (const double b, const Matrix& a)
{
    //your code
    return yourobject;
}
```